# Is there a tracking script for linkedin

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

Is there a way to log the name of a person that has loged to my website using linkedin?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create an application that uses [LinkedIn authentication](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication), but it doesn't look like they provide a sript that allows you to track people who haven't given you explicit permission.

Comment: Yes, to know if the current viewer is logged in to LinkedIn definitively, they would have to have granted the website permission to access their LinkedIn profile.